# Se duplican datos en SQL al contar en dos tablas

Tags: sql

tengo una consulta y es que al intentar contar dos valores que se repiten en dos tabla los primeros valores me dan bien pero a partir del segundo empieza a contar cualquier cosa.

Tengo dos tablas una LIBRO y otra PRESTAMO

Este es el codigo para contar y unir las dos tablas:

```
SELECT LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO,
    LIBRO.TITULO,
    NRO_COPIA,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(NRO_COPIA)
        FROM PRESTAMO
        WHERE LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO = PRESTAMO.NRO_LIBRO
        ) AS CANT
FROM PRESTAMO
JOIN LIBRO ON LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO = PRESTAMO.NRO_LIBRO
GROUP BY LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO,
    LIBRO.TITULO,
    PRESTAMO.NRO_COPIA
```

El reslutado de ese codigo es:

[image: RESULTADO]

Al hacer la misma consulta solo en la tabla PRESTAMO me da estos resultados
este es el codigo que uso en PRESTAMO:

```
SELECT NRO_LIBRO,
    NRO_COPIA,
    COUNT(NRO_COPIA) AS CANT
FROM PRESTAMO
GROUP BY NRO_LIBRO,
    NRO_COPIA
ORDER BY NRO_LIBRO
```

y este es el resultado:

[image: RESULTADO PRESTAMO]

Lo que necesito es que la columna CANT sea igual en los dos codigos pero en el primero me da una suma extraña.

Comment: Pásanos el dataset  en SQL con phpmyadmin->exportar y dinos qué cantidades esperabas obtener...

Comment: Es muy probable que el problema sea el título, prueba a ponerlo en el SELECT con un función de agregación, por ejemplo: `MAX(LIBRO.TITULO) AS TITULO,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que `NRO_LIBRO` es una llave primaria en la tabla `LIBRO`, no necesitas hacer la subconsulta relacionada. La solución es mucho más simple.

```
SELECT LL.NRO_LIBRO,
    L.TITULO,
    P.NRO_COPIA,
    COUNT(*) AS CANT
FROM PRESTAMO P
JOIN LIBRO    L ON L.NRO_LIBRO = P.NRO_LIBRO
GROUP BY L.NRO_LIBRO,
    L.TITULO,
    P.NRO_COPIA
```

Como dato adicional, el problema que tiene tu subconsulta relacionada es que no estás relacionando por el número de copia, por lo que muestra todos los prestamos por título y no por copia. Para corregirlo, tendrías que hacerlo así.

```
SELECT LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO,
    LIBRO.TITULO,
    NRO_COPIA,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(NRO_COPIA)
        FROM PRESTAMO P2
        WHERE LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO = P2.NRO_LIBRO
        AND PRESTAMO.NRO_COPIA = P2.NRO_COPIA
        ) AS CANT
FROM PRESTAMO
JOIN LIBRO ON LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO = PRESTAMO.NRO_LIBRO
GROUP BY LIBRO.NRO_LIBRO,
    LIBRO.TITULO,
    PRESTAMO.NRO_COPIA
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder ahora funciona !